# Python remove similar items from list

Tags: python, list, reduce, similarity

Using python, in the following list I need to remove phone numbers which are repeated with country codes.

```
['(+44)45860787163','(+27)16345860787','45860787163','16345860787']
```

I tried using Cartesian product and 'in' operator to compare strings but nothing seems to be working.
What I'd like to keep are the full phone numbers.

```
['(+44)45860787163','(+27)16345860787']
```

Comment: Do you have a string with a list in it, or a list of strings?

Comment: I have it as a list of strings

Comment: the example you gave is a string? its enclosed in ```''```

Comment: I have suggested an edit with a list of strings, assuming that that was a typo.

Comment: have you tried a regex solution?

Comment: no, can you give me more hints on regex idea?

Comment: The answers so far appear to just get rid of the numbers without country codes. That is rather easy, as you do not need to compare anything. Could it be that there are numbers which are ONLY available without country codes in the list, and then you would wish to keep these (in spite of the absence of country code)?

Comment: yes, that is a possibility too. So in 45860787163 and 045860787163 I would prefer to keep the longer one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension

```
l = ['(+44)45860787163','(+27)16345860787','45860787163','16345860787']

l = [x for x in l if '(' in x]

print(l)

>>> ['(+44)45860787163', '(+27)16345860787']
```

If you want to be extra secure you can check for both semi colons

```
l = [x for x in l if '(' in x and ')' in x]
```

Comment: The OP wants to keep the phone numbers with the `(+xx)`. This does the opposite

Comment: This was my first thought on how to approach this but I think the OP is looking to return the numbers with area codes

Answer (score 3):

Using a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/dpNlyO/1) you may extract the part you need, then using a dict, you can pair the number with its prefix (and avoid overwriting a prefix)

```
value = '(+44)45860787163,(+27)16345860787,45860787163,16345860787'
phones = {}

for phone, prefix, number in re.findall(r"((\(\+\d+\))?(\d+))", value):
    if prefix != "" or number not in phone:
        phones[number] = prefix

result = ",".join(v + k for k, v in phones.items())
print(result)  # (+44)45860787163,(+27)16345860787
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we get all the phone numbers. Then, we create a dictionary with number without extension as key and extension as value. If a number hasn't extension it's set to None. After, if we find the same number with extension None is replaced by the extension. At the end, we print the number with the corresponding extension.

```
numbers = '(+44)45860787163,(+27)16345860787,45860787163,16345860787'.split(',')
d = dict()
for number in numbers:
    if ')' in number:
        prefix, n = number.split(')')
        prefix = prefix + ')'
    else:
        prefix = None
        n = number
    if n in d.keys():
        if d[n] == None:
            d[n] = prefix
    else:
        d[n] = prefix
print([k if v == None else v + k for k,v in d.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
number_string = '(+44)45860787163,(+27)16345860787,45860787163,16345860787'

result = []

for phone_number in number_string.split(','):
    if "(" in phone_number:
        result.append(phone_number)

print(result)
```